# Change skewY angle onresize of window

Tags: javascript, html, css, getuikit

No jQuery and no SCCS please (even though I am using UIkit3 for styling here). The navbar has a slanted background image, this is done with a linear-gradient and fixed height in CSS. My approach is to use transform: skewY and changing the angle value onresize.
I can see the value changing in the console, but it does not seem to affect the site.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
w = window.innerWidth;
h = 140;
document.getElementById('Rhombus').style.transform="skewY('-Math.atan(h/w)*180/Math.PI )+'deg)";

alpha = Math.atan(h/w)*180/Math.PI;
console.log(w, h, -alpha);
};
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/rdvorak/pen/LwVGym)

The container #Rhombus below should also use the same angle as the header.

Comment: Thanks! Corrected on codepen "skewY("-Math.atan(h/w)*180/Math.PI )+"deg)"; - but still not doing what I want it to. SInce I am new I can't seem to edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a syntax error in the string `"skewY('-Math.atan(h/w)*180/Math.PI )+'deg)"` try to use ES6 String Substitution like this :

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
w = window.innerWidth;
h = 140;
alpha = Math.atan(h/w)*180/Math.PI;
document.getElementById('Rhombus').style.transform="skewY(`${-alpha}deg`)";
console.log(w, h, -alpha);

};
```

Comment: Thank you, tried it, but behvaviour is the same - I think I have maybe an error in my thinking. The angle shown in the console log is correct, so the JS is working - but it does not seem to affect the target div...

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to get to the next step - first post, so I can't mark your input as helpful,#

Comment: It's OK, I glad I helped you find the answer

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution by using CSS variables and updating those in JS:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
root = document.documentElement;
w = window.innerWidth;
h = 140;
alpha = Math.atan(h/w)*180/Math.PI;
document.getElementById('Rhombus').style.transform="skewY(`${-alpha}deg`)";
console.log(w, h, -alpha);
root.style.setProperty('--atan', -alpha + "deg");
root.style.setProperty('--tan', alpha + "deg");
};
```